# Mac Pro Boot Camp w/ RAID card

Tags: raid, boot-camp, mac

If I configure a Mac Pro with a RAID card and two 15k RPM drives, and leave the drives JBOD (no RAID configured), can I install Windows on the second drive? I guess the question really is, does Windows recognize the RAID card? I know it's probably just a rebadged LSI or Adaptec but wanted to see if anyone's actually done it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found a true answer for this, but abandoned it because it likely would have involved tinkering with the firmware of the card.  Wasn't a good idea.